# How to use non-deprecated tools like ss to get process id running on a port?

Tags: port, localhost, socket, netstat

I am looking for a non-deprecated way of running a command like `netstat -tulpn | grep 8000` to output information about an active port. Any suggestions on how to use a tool like `ss` to get the process id?

I have a localhost running on port 8000, but `ss -a | grep 8000` does not output anything. Running `fuser 8000/tcp` outputs the port's process, as does `netstat -tulpn | grep 8000`. Why doesn't the `ss` command output anything about my port?

Comment: Does `ss -na | grep 8000` output something ? What kind of information would you like to retrieve about an active port ?

Comment: Thanks! The `n` flag was key, although it is very subtle. I was just trying to get the process number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use lsof with the -i option. IE: `lsof -i:80` for view what's listening on port 80.

Also you can use `ss -tlpn` to view all processes listening for ports.

Regards